# How to create multiple attachments in one call with cradle

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb, cradle

I'm working on a nodejs application and am inserting two attachments to a couchdb with cradle.  Currently I am inserting the first attachment, getting the updated doc, and then inserting the second attachment with the updated _rev key.  This is inefficient causing me to have to make two separate calls to couchdb.

Is there a way to create multiple attachments with a single cradle call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CouchDB supports creating multiple attachments at once, See http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/document/common.html#creating-multiple-attachments for details. I don’t think cradle supports any of these, though, but I might be wrong. Should be easy to add and a good PR to send against cradle :)

Comment: I didn't think it natively support it. I guess I'll file something against cradle (and maybe even write it myself)